# Cannot read "files" in HTTP Foundation Symfony 3.3

Tags: php, symfony, file-upload, symfony-http-foundation

Recently I updated a symfony project from 3.2 to 3.3. 
I have an issue with a simple POST with a file. The file is not in the filebag of the http foundation object Request.

```
public function sendAction(Request $request){
    dump($request->files);
    dump($request->request);
    dump($request->headers);
    if (!$request->files->has("image")) {
        throw new HttpException(Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST, 'no "image" field');
    }
}
```

When I have a look at what it dumped, 
depending on the content-type of the request, I have different results :

If I use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as header, I have these dump : https://pastebin.com/5HSCAgut (sorry for pastebin links, output is too long)

If i use `multipart/form-data` as header, I have these dumps : 
https://pastebin.com/tZdVKNgG

What's wrong with my script ? Am i missing a new feature or security check ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it was a stupid client error. I specified the header :

```
Content-type: multipart/form-data
```

but it should be

```
Content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=-------------BOUNDARYUSEDINREQUEST--------------
```